# how to create Image slideshow for android?

Tags: android

I want to develop a image slideshow or animation like Gif animation for android. 3 or 4 images  will be there and each image will display alternately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at Android [APIDemo.](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. I have seen it. But I missed to see in view.

Comment: which one should be imported?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a ViewFlipper and create a thread that sleeps for the delay you want between frames, then shows the next image.

```
public class YourFlipperActivity extends Activity {

protected void yourFlipperForward() {
    // Set animation
    tflipper.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            YourFlipperActivity.this, R.anim.slide_in));

    // Show next step
    tflipper.showNext();

}

protected void yourFlipperBack() {
    // Set animation
    tflipper.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            YourFlipperActivity.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));

    // Show next step
    tflipper.showPrevious();

}

private ViewFlipper tflipper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    tflipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.your_flipperid);
}

public void close(View v) {
    finish();
}

public void flipNext(View v) {
    yourFlipperForward();
}

public void flipPrevious(View v) {
    yourFlipperBack();
}
}
```

Next, you'll want to create an aSync task that loops your flipNext method.

Something like:

```
private class YourPollTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer> {
    /**
     * The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and delivers
     * it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute()
     */
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... millis) {
        try {
            int waited = 0;
            int duration = millis[0].intValue();
            while (waited < duration) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                waited += 1000;
                flipNext();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // do nothing
        }

        return 1;
    }
```

Good luck with that.

Alternately, if you want to use an actual animated gif, you could use [GifSplitter](http://www.xoyosoft.com/gs/download/gs.zip), which is free. I don't recommend using animated gifs, though, because they are pretty old-school.